# AVL tree worst case number of rotations during insertion and deletion

Tags: data-structures, tree, avl-tree

In an AVL tree, what is the worst case number of rotations during insertion and deletion of n elements ?

I think for insertion it should be O(n) and for deletion it should be O(nlogn). However, I am not that much sure about deletion .

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both operations - inserting or deleting of a node *x*, there are cases that require rotations to be made on all nodes from *x* up to the root. Since height of a tree with *n* nodes is *O(log n)*, the worst case for both operations take *O(log n)* rotations. For *n* insert/delete operations that gives *O(n log n)*.

Comment: For inserting an element, maximum we can have 2 rotations, so for n elements we can have 2n or O(n) rotations right ?

Comment: You do not perform rotations on all elements, only on the inserted one and its ancestors.

Each time you insert/delete a node *x*, beside the broken height balance on *x* there is a possibility that it's broken also on a parent of *x*. Thus,
beside the rotations on *x*, you have to check if they required on the *x*'s parent. Recursively, you traverse from *x* up to the root until no rotations are required. In the worst case, you would finish rotating the root, which gives *O(log n)* time.

Comment: Yes, you need to travel till root which requires o(logn) when you insert an element. But you end up doing only 2 rotations at maximum for one element. In the question I am only concerned with number of rotations and not traversing.

Comment: Argh, I see your point. It's correct that you need at most 2 rotations per an inserted element. But, in order to keep the AVL criteria true, you need to traverse up to the root. So, it's at most *2 log n = O(log n)* rotations per an element. For *n* elements, it's *O(n log n)* rotations.

Comment: Even for deletion is it O(logn) rotations per element ?

Comment: Yes, because you have to traverse all ancestors of the inserted element (while balance is broken) and perform rotations. In the worst case, it will go up to the root.

Comment: @karastojko, isn't that the case that when we perform rotation to balance some node it's hight gets reduced by 1. So it's parent need not be balanced. Ref: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/97999/101527

Comment: @VimalPatel After the rotation, the parent might have balance +2 or -2, thus one has to proceed with the rotations upwards. You can find details in the [tutorial](http://alepho.com/programming/20120126/avl_tree.pdf) I wrote some time ago.

Comment: It would be great if you provide an explicit example where after insertion into AVL tree more than single node require balancing?

Comment: @VimalPatel Just make an example of a tree where after deleting the node `x` each ancestor of `x` gets balance +2 or -2. Then the algorithm has to traverse all the ancestors and rotate them.

Comment: @karastojko, Yes you are write. But can you provide example for INSERT case? For case of insert at most one node needs to be balanced. Explicitly the lowest node on path from root to newly inserted node that is imbalanced needs to be balanced. Once it gets balanced it's height decreases by one(effectively it hight gets updated to what that was before insertion of new node.) so no node further on path to the root needs to be fixed.

Comment: @VimalPatel Ah sorry, I should reply about the inserting. When you insert a node `x`, you put it at the lowest level of the tree and update balances of all nodes from the root down to `x`. If balances of all nodes on that path are updated to +2 or -2, then all of them have to be rotated.